# Can't create entity object with map with custom object

Tags: spring-boot, spring-boot-jpa

Spring boot 2.5

I has entity `Cart`. One cart has many entities `Product`. In one cart has many products. So I try with  `@JoinColumn` but I get error:

```
@Entity
public class Cart {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private int id;
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "cart", fetch = FetchType.EAGER,
            cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private Map<Product, Integer> products;
}


import javax.persistence.*;

@Entity
public class Product {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private int id;
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, optional = false)
    @JoinColumn(name = "cart_id", nullable = false)
    private Cart cart;
}
```

But when I try to run application I get error:

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'mvcConversionService' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/web/servlet/WebMvcAutoConfiguration$EnableWebMvcConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.format.support.FormattingConversionService]: Factory method 'mvcConversionService' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'cartRepository' defined in com.myproject.eshop_orders.repo.CartRepository defined in @EnableJpaRepositories declared on JpaRepositoriesRegistrar.EnableJpaRepositoriesConfiguration: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'jpaMappingContext' while setting bean property 'mappingContext'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'jpaMappingContext': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.AnnotationException: Use of @OneToMany or @ManyToMany targeting an unmapped class: com.myproject.eshop_orders.api.model.Cart.products[java.lang.Integer]
```

Comment: when do you get this error? on doing what?

Comment: Whet  run applcation

Comment: I think you need to swap the arguments  private Map<Product, Integer> products; to  private Map<Integer, Product> products;

Comment: @Rakesh I can't swap because integer is a quantity of products

Comment: Use List<Product> products

Comment: @AbinashGhosh I need to store quantity of products. To do this I want to use Map<Product, Integer>

Comment: Okay then you need a mapping table also many to many relationship

Comment: @AbinashGhosh I added my answer. Is this a correct?

Answer (score 0):

If you want a map you need to use `@MapKeyJoinColumn`. Something like this

```
@Entity
public class Cart {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private int id;

    @MapKeyJoinColumn(name="PRODUCT_ID")
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "cart", fetch = FetchType.EAGER,
            cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private Map<Product, Integer> products;
}
```

Comment: Not help. Get same error.  Use of OneToMany or ManyToMany targeting an unmapped class: com.myproject.eshop_orders.api.model.Cart.products[java.lang.Integer]

Comment: @s_subscriber wants quantity as map value

Answer (score 0):

One cart has many different products. 
Also I need to store quantity of products in cart (value in map)

Here my solution:

```
@Entity
public class Cart {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private int id;
     @ElementCollection
    @CollectionTable(name = "cart_products", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "cart_id"))
    @MapKeyJoinColumn(name = "product_id")
    @Column(name = "product_qantity")
    private Map<Product, Integer> products;

}


import javax.persistence.*;

@Entity
public class Product {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private int id;
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, optional = false)
    @JoinColumn(name = "cart_id", nullable = false)
    private Cart cart;
}
```

Is this a correct solution?